# Why protected scope is not working?

Tags: java, protected

I am trying an exercise with Java's protected scope.

I have a Base class in package1:

```
package package1;

 public class Base {

     protected String messageFromBase = "Hello World";

    protected void display(){
        System.out.println("Base Display");
    }

}
```

and I have a Neighbour class in same package:

```
package package1;

public class Neighbour {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b =  new Base();
        b.display();
    }
}
```

Then I have a child class in another package, which inherits from Base  from package1:

```
package package2;

import package1.Base;

 class Child extends Base {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base1 = new Base();
        base1.display(); // invisible
        System.out.println(" this is not getting printed" + base1.messageFromBase); // invisible

    }


}
```

My problem is that the `display()` method is not getting called from the child instance.  Also, `base1.messageFromBase` is not accessible although they are declared as protected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note some things about `protected` access

```
-They are available in the package using object of class
-They are available outside the package only through inheritance
-You cannot create object of a class and call the `protected` method outside package on it
```

they are only called through inheritance outside package. You do not have to create object of base class and then call, you can simply call `display()`

```
class Child extends Base {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child child = new Child();
    child.display(); 
  }
}
```

An expert Makoto has provided the link for official documention in the answer he has provided.

Comment: class Child extends Base  (  inheritance  is mentioned there). and child lies in separate package

Comment: You already inherited `display` method, you just need to use it or `Override `it

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain:  Overriding it would be a bad idea in this scenario, as it means you're usurping the behavior of the parent method.  That's likely not what's intended here.

Comment: I know, thats what I tried to explain, all possible behaviours

Answer (score 1):

You're using the *parent* class, not the *child* class, when you're attempting to call the protected method and access the protected field.  Since you're inside of `main`, not using an instance of `Child`, and [not in the same package as `Base`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), you won't have access to the field or method through the parent alone.

You should create a new instance of `Child` can invoke the methods you want instead.

```
 class Child extends Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.display();
        System.out.println(" this will get printed" + child.messageFromBase);

    }
}
```

Comment: methods are also not accessible through following relationship Base base1 = new Child();

Comment: @Orion:  I wouldn't expect it to.  You're referring to an instance of a `Child` as an instance of `Base` in a context where you don't have visibility into `Base`'s protected classes.

Comment: Methods are called on reference type. Here you have reference of Base class. Compiler thinks you want to call a protected method using object